# Applying background color to telerik MVC combo box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, telerik-combobox

Could you please help me setting the background color of my MVC telerik combobox using jQuery? I tried few but that didnt work. Any help will be appreciated!!

```
if ($("#ComboID").hasClass("backgroundColorClass");) {    
 $("#ComboID").addClass("backgroundColorClass");    
}


$("#ComboID").css("border","border details");    
$("#ComboID").css("background-color","#color");`
```

So, basically my question is, how can I set the InputHtmlAttributes/ DropDownHtmlAttributes/ HtmlAttributes of the telerik MVC combobox using jquery?

Thanks in advance,
Evolving Techie

---

I was able to fix the issue with the belowcode:

```
if ($("#ComboID").hasClass("backgroundColorClass")) {
 $("#ComboID").removeClass("backgroundColorClass");
}

if (! $("#ComboID").hasClass("backgroundColorClass")) {
 $("#ComboID").addClass("backgroundColorClass");
}
```

Comment: you can answer your own question and mark as correct